# Understanding the difference in behaviour between perl's assign-or operator and the combination of assignment and logical-or operators

Tags: perl, operators, evaluation, autovivification

Today I was surprised when I came across the following behaviour in perl:

```
sub f { die if %{ $_[0] }; 42 }
my %h;
$h{x} ||= f(\%h); # we die. $_[0] references a hash with an 'x' key during f's run-time
```

In contrast, given the same set-up, the following statement behaves differently.

```
$h{x} = $h{x} || f(\%h); # $h{x} is now 42
```

Is this potential difference between assign-or and the combination of assignment and logical-or documented somewhere?

If this is due to auto-vivification, is it a bug or missing feature in the `autovivification` module which doesn't seem to be able to detect auto-vivification in this particular construct?

Comment: This is why it's better to use `exists` to see if a hash element exists or not.

Comment: Why hello there.

Answer (score 6):

Key pieces of info:

- `||` and `||=` are short-circuiting, so they must evaluate their left-hand side before their right-hand side. (This allows `f() || die()`.)
- `=` evaluates its right-hand side operand before its left-hand side. (This allows `$x = f($x)`.)
- The left-hand side of `||=` is only evaluated once.
- Hash elements aren't vivify (created) on access unless necessary (i.e. in an lvalue context).

---

Let's look at `$h{x} = $h{x} || f(\%h);`.

From the above, we conclude the following:

- Only the left-most `$h{x}` needs to vivify the element.
- The left-most `$h{x}` is evaluated after `f` returns.

---

Let's look at `$h{x} ||= f(\%h);`.

From the above, we conclude the following:

- `$h{x}` must be evaluated before the call to `f`.
- Evaluating `$h{x}` must produce a modifiable value, so it must vivify `$h{x}`.

---

Lvalue Context

- Left-hand side of assignment operators (incl `||=`).
- Operand of pre/post-increment/decrement.
- Operand of `\`.
- Foreach loop list expression (because of `$_ = uc($_) for @a;`).
- Subroutine arguments (because of `sub ucip { $_[0] = uc($_[0]) }`), but see "One Exception" below.
- Others?

---

One Exception

If you pass `$h{x}` to a sub, Perl actually passes a magical scalar which proxies `$h{x}` instead. This is done to prevent vivification if possible. It's not cheap, but it avoids a lot of nasty surprises.

It is possible for Perl to delay vivification in `$h{x} ||= f(\%h);` using the same mechanism, but it's not worth the expense.

Comment: Thank you! The implementation of the evaluation order seems to be controlled by the ASSIGN_BACKWARDS flag (BKWARD in dump.c / Concise), and looking at the code I think I now understand why I'm seeing the behaviour described. Would you happen to have any reference to the mechanism delaying vivification of hash elements for function calls that I could search the source code for?

Comment: You can see it using `perl -MDevel::Peek -e'sub { Dump($_[0]) }->($h{x});'`. Built-in magics are in `mg.c`.

Comment: It basically creates a scalar that contains the hash and the key, and modifies said hash and key when the scalar is modified, causing the element's vivification if it didn't already exist.

Comment: Would you consider this behaviour to be a feature of the language, or more of an artifact of the implementation? I tried to look through the various low-level sassign tests, but didn't spot anything that seemed like it'd fail if the behaviour was to change.

Comment: A necessary consequence of the four items I listed, all of which could be considered features. You could work around it (as done for parameters), which comes down to cost balancing.

Answer (score 2):

The critical bit is that merely checking on a key doesn't autovivify it

```
perl -Mstrict -wE'my %h; if ($h{k}) { say "yes" }; say "Exists" if exists $h{k}'
```

Prints nothing; key `k` has not been added to the hash.  (One needs more for autovivification to kick in, like to test nested keys -- then the ones leading up to the last one must be created.)

This explains how the two cases differ: with `||=` the `$h{x}` is being *assigned to* when the sub `f` runs<sup>†</sup> and so key `x` must be first created for the purpose of that assignment, while in the other case `$h{x}` is only checked before the sub `f` runs, so no autovivification happens.

I don't know the actual implementation of `||=` nor did I find any specific statement in the docs.

---

<sup>†</sup> The `||=` is [listed as an assignment operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Assignment-Operators)

Comment: We both have the same expectations as to what auto-vivification should do. I mainly mentioned it because auto-vivification is the closest behaviour in perl I know of that might cause what we're observing. I'd be surprised if it was at play here, though - at least intentionally.

Comment: The precedence described in the documentation linked is a compile-time thing only. I'm interested in the difference in run-time behaviour between the two different op-trees.

Comment: You're confusing precedence and operand evaluation order. Only the latter is relevant here.

Comment: @ikegami  Not confusing them -- that statement on the precedence (in the docs) is a hint of the evaluation order.  That's what I mean

Comment: They're completely unrelated concepts. In fact, `=` and `||=` have *different* operand evaluation orders (which is particularly relevant).

Comment: @ikegami "_completely unrelated concepts_" --- hang on ... if something has precedence over the other it is likely evaluated before the other ... ?  Not guaranteed but it is a "hint" ...?

Comment: yes, but noone thinks that `$h{x} = $h{x} || f(\%h);` means `( $h{x} = $h{x} ) || f(\%h);`, so that's not relevant. Only the order in which `x` and `y` are evaluated in `x = y` and the order in which they are evaluated in `x ||= y` is relevant here, and they're *different*.  And that's key to the answer.

Comment: The answer is correct, but the footnote is some mix of confusing/wrong/misleading. If the order was the same, both would die.

Comment: @ikegami "_... but the footnote is ..._"  --- alright, i see now what you mean specifically.  Was looking in the docs for _anything_ related to any degree to the issue ...  need to go now will review a little later.  Thang you for comments as always!

Comment: Re docs: The short-circuiting nature of `||` and `||=` dictates their OEO. Unless it's changed, `=`'s OEO isn't explicitly documented. But the docs make clear you can do `local $x = $x;`, which strongly implies it. (This is can all be confirmed using `-MO=Concise,-exec` or using `sub f :lvalue { say "..."; ... }` as an operand.)